# How to divide map into square grid using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I want to divide a map in square grid using ArcGIS Desktop.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try the [Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/0017/00170000002q000000.htm) tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an equidistant grid in ArcGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119733/create-an-equidistant-grid-in-arcgis)

Answer (score 1):

Create a fishnet using the fishnet tool, then do an intersect procedure. The resulting data set will be a combination of your original data set and the fishnet. You could alternatively use ready-made square grids like the [Quarter Degree Grid Cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QDGC) system.